# Why loadComplete fires before gridComplete?

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to manipulate the data fetched from the server in loadComplete event:

```
loadComplete:function(data){
    alert("load completed");
    $.each (data,function(index,item){

    item["customerSite"]=item.header.customerName + ' / '+item.header.siteDescription;
    });
}
```

The newly added field is meant to be used as a column to be grouped by
However I keep getting this column as undefined as grouping header. I tried adding another field to the JSON object as a regular column, the column ends up to be empty. As I was debugging I noticed the grid is constructed before my breakpoint in the loadComplete stops.

My understanding of the loadComplete event is that it will fired as soon as the ajax call has success return. After I introduced gridComplete event to my code, I noticed gridComplete is invoked before loadComplete is invoked.

```
gridComplete: function(){ 
    alert("grid completed");
}
```

What I am doing wrong? I am using

```
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                id: "id",
                root: function (obj) { return obj; },
                page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
            }
```

to process returned JSON string, but cannot imagine that might be the problem. Please help!

Base on Oleg's comment, I will use custom formatter. However the result of the fomratter does not work for the group header, which this column is for. If I set groupColumnShow : [true], the column's data is all correct, but still leaves the group header to be 'undefined'

Following grid's definition:

```
buildGrid:function(){
        var myGrid = jQuery("#serverList");

        myGrid.jqGrid({

        datatype: "json",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/cm.server/api/v1/agent/config.json?",
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "id",
            root: function (obj) { return obj; },
            page: function (obj) { return 1; },
            total: function (obj) { return 1; },
            records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
        },              
        colNames:['Customer/Site','Customer','Site','Server ID', 'Server Name', ,'id'],

        colModel :[ 
              {name:'customerSite',editable:false, formatter:that.buildCustmerSite},   
              {name:'header.customerName',hidden:true,editable:true,editrules:{edithidden:true},editoptions:{readonly:true,size:25},formoptions:{ rowpos:1,elmprefix:"&nbsp;"}},

              {name:'header.siteDescription', hidden:true, editable:true,editrules:{edithidden:true},editoptions:{readonly:true,size:25},formoptions:{ rowpos:2,elmprefix:"&nbsp;"}},         

              {name:'header.serverID', index:'header.serverID', width:200, align:'right',editable:true,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:25},formoptions:{ rowpos:3,elmprefix:"&nbsp;"}},

              {name:'header.serverName', index:'header.serverName', width:150, align:'right',editable:true,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:25},formoptions:{ rowpos:4,elmprefix:"&nbsp;"}},

              {name:'id', hidden:true},

            ],
            height: '500',
            width: '100%',
            rowNum:20,
            autowidth: true,
            pager: '#pager',
            sortname: 'serverID',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'Server Configurations',
            editurl:"/cm.server/api/v1/agent/config-grid",
            autoencode:true,
            ignoreCase:true,
            grouping:true,
            groupingView:{
                groupField:['customerSite'],
                groupColumnShow : [false]
            }
          });

      jQuery("#serverList").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
      {edit:true,add:false,del:false,search:true}, 
      {height:450,reloadAfterSubmit:true,  recreateForm:true,jqModal:true, closeOnEscape:true,  closeAfterEdit:true, bottominfo:"Fields marked with (*) are required"}, // edit options
            {} // search options
        );
      jQuery("#serverList").jqGrid('filterToolbar'); 
      return true;
    }
```

and following is the custom formatter:

```
buildCustmerSite:function(cellvalue,options,rowObject){
    var customerSite =rowObject.header['customerName'] + '/'+ rowObject.header["siteDescription"];
    return customerSite;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are small differences between `loadComplate` and `gridComplete`, but both will be called **after** the grid contain is prepared. So you can't just modify the `data` of the `loadComplate` to change the grid contain.

You don't posted the definition of your grid, so it is difficult to answer on your question exactly. What you probably want can be solved with respect of the [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) which you can define for the `customerSite` column. Inside of formatter function you have access to `rowObject` where you find source information to construct the `customerName` + ' / ' + `siteDescription`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg! I expect loadComplete is fired before the grid's content is prepared. If it is not, I have to use a custom formatter as you suggested. I had pasted the grid's construction code in my question body. The problem there is that group header still shows as 'undefined' even the formatter function is called nicely. If I set the groupColumnShow:[true] instead of false, the column is shown with the right data. It appears to me the formatter does not work for the grouping header..

Comment: @xueru: Could you post the test JSON data which can be used to reproduce the problem? It can be that the problem exist because of points inside of `name` properties of the `colModel`.

Comment: You are right about the name properties of the colModel of the column that is being grouped on. I have 'customerSite' for the column, but it is not in the json object fetched from the server. I attempted to add it to the return result set in the loadComplete, since that is not called at the timing I expected, with the current approach using custom formatter I need to specify a right name property for the column. Thanks a million! I wish Stackflow allows me to send you some credit for coffee as my gratitude. It would be a nice feature to have for Stackflow...

Comment: @xueru: You are welcome! I am glad to hear that I could help you. Your good words are better as money. Tank you! Just drink to my health and we're even. Good luck!